# What is the right form of this relational db design?

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

Below I have two tables, Customer and Currency.

Scenario : Each customer must have one currency defined for all their transactions. I have placed a currency_id column which associate the currency to the customer. Below are some question arise in my mind. Mybe it is silly question. But I would like to clear myself.

1. View from Customer : One customer has one currency
   [image]
2. View from Currency : One currency can have 0 or more customer.
   [image]

Here the question. In this types of scenario, how we should take the issue? We should see from customer (1) or from currency (2). Anybody can explain me this??

EDIT : My question is in terms of designing the ERD.

Comment: Sorry... I'm having a little trouble understanding your question.

Comment: please look at the others answer. it will be clear thogh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Tossing this in after upvoting @Gilbert's reply and reading the ensuing discussion.)

A relationship between two tables goes both ways: table X is related to table Y, and table Y is related to table X. For your case, it’s excactly as you said:

- One customer has one currency
- One currency can have 0 or more customers

Both verbal descriptions are correct.

With regards to ERD representation, your second case best represents this. Unless you’re an academic, don’t get bogged down with representational minutiae, there are dozens of very similar notations out there. So long as it shows “One to zero or more”, you’re good.

As for implementation, I think you’ve already got that down pat: Parent table has Primary key (CurrencyId), child table has its own Primary key (CustomerID) and a foreign key (CurrenctyID) related back to the parent table.

Comment: well explained ! thanx everyone

Answer (score 1):

> We should see from customer (1) or from currency (2).

You can see the data from either the customer point of view or the currency point of view.

You said it yourself.  You can see the currency for a particular customer, or you can count the number of customers for a particular currency.

There's no "order" for going through a relational database.  You design the relational tables so they provide the information you need.

Comment: I see one design.  You can look at the data from the point of view of the customer, or the point of view of the currency.

Comment: @Martin Wilson: Why not?  You have CurrencyID as the primary key of Currency and a foreign key in Customer.

Comment: The fields are right, certainly- I'm pretty sure the question is about which notation is most correct in terms of the lines denoting the relationship. I would have said 2 but you're making me doubt my (rusty) ERD skills!

Comment: @Martin Wilson:  As I said, 1 & 2 are both necessary. You need the required constraint on the foreign key in the Customer table, and the Currency has to exist for a Customer to choose it.  (Actually not.  The application could insert a new Currency row first, commit, then insert the foreign key into the Customer row.)

Comment: @MartinWilson, the above question is exactly in terms of designing ERD. I know the function what both tables can do. What I want to know is how to represent them.

Comment: @Gilbert - you wouldn't show 1 and 2 (i.e. two lines) on an ERD for this relationship.

Answer (score 0):

On terms of an ERD 2 is correct. You have a foreign key in Customer referencing the primary key of Currency, so you have a many-to-one relationship from Customer to Currency. 2 correctly shows this relationship diagrammatically.

Answer (score 0):

You don't view the relationship from either side. What you have here is zero-to-many customers relating to one currency, expressible graphically or as text in a number of different ways. "0..*:1", for example.